# 'User' and 'Official' use seperation in Infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath

I have a Request/Change form created with 3 views.
First view for the User (Requester) to fill in.
Second and third view for team to action.
Objective is, that either the User should not be able to go the next 2 forms
OR
If he might go to the next 2 forms through the next buttons, the forms should be read only BUT if that is the case, how would the team that would action or handle the form edit the view 2 and view 3 pages?
Please assist. Need urgent help! Have to submit by Monday....

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can handle this. First you could have a section for the "Next" buttons that will only show if the correct users open the form. This way the requester would not be able to see the next 2 views. The other way to approach if you want the requester to be able to see the other two sections would be to create two extra views where the information is read only and have the other views that are not read only accessible to the correct users. The basic idea would be to create a formatting rule where it would hide and show sections depending upon which user is viewing the form.